# Can I use qt quick compiler in Qt4.8.5

Tags: qt, qt-quick

I see there is one tool Qt Quick Compiler that can compile QML source code into the final binary.

But currently my I'm working on the Qt4.8.5, can I use this tool? or it can only be used in the Qt5.3?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot use the tool with older versions of Qt.

According to [QtQuickCompiler Known Issues](http://doc.qt.digia.com/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-known-issues.html):

> The compiler is strictly tied to the Qt version due to its use of internal data structures. At this point we cannot guarantee binary and source compatibilities for these internal data structures and therefore when upgrading to a new Qt version, an update of the compiler is required. It is also necessary to re-compile previously compiled .qml files when upgrading the compiler. This means the compiler is currently not suited for software ecosystems with QML based libraries and independently released applications using those

This would imply that the QtQuickCompiler is strictly tied to Qt 5.3, which is the version it was first released with. Since there are no releases for older versions of Qt, you are out of luck.